# What is /dev/null?

Tags: command-line, filesystem

I just changed my Windows OS to Ubuntu and want to understand how to use it effectively.

I saw commands where a user sends files to `/dev/null`.
What goes after moving some file to `/dev/null`? What are the use cases of`/dev/null`?

Sorry if it's an incorrect question. Will really appreciate any answers.

Comment: See the manual page `man null`: 'Data written to the /dev/null and /dev/zero special files is discarded.'

Comment: [Overview of `/dev/null`](https://www.linux.org/threads/overview-of-dev-null.11641/)